# Spend Your time in read and out of write lock scope

Tags: mongodb

I was going through MongoDB Performance tuning and came across this in this website

http://www.scribd.com/fullscreen/56271132?access_key=key-1hnjbdbd1h36109o86zd&allow_share=true&view_mode=scroll

The above site has got a following line

**Read -before -write**

```
Spend Your time in read and out of write lock scope 
50 % reduction in lock %
```

Could anybody please tell me ,
What does this mean actually ??

Comment: Hmm not sure actually, a quick google search does not help and those notes were written as notes. Certainly increasing read lock won't reduce lock % it will increase it

Answer (score 1):

I think it refers to the fact that writing locks the collection and you want to minimize that.  I think it is saying you should read first, then write, so you don't have to make a read but wait for a write.

generally you use a memcache system so your reads don't have to wait for collection writes to be done/unlocked and avoid write locks altogether. then again if the information isn't in the memcache, it will read it from the actual collection and it might have to wait for a write lock then.

read more about memcache, there are some memcache frameworks for servers that mongodb out there, like for php and for nodejs.

Comment: Hmm your English suggests that Memcached is part of MongoDB, the first paragraph makes sense but the latter two don't.

Comment: "generally you use a memcache system"  Source?  My understanding is that MongoDB's performance characteristics meant that memcache is largely redundant... not a general companion.

Comment: what is faster, querying the sharded database or getting it from a variable in your server? when you have millions of documents, the answer is quite obvious.

Comment: A memcache server could be just as distanced from the web server as the database itself

Comment: yes, unless it isn't :D case by case scenarios call for different solutions.

Comment: Hmm it is very rare that the memcache server would be on the app server unless you was using a redundant setup that didn't really need it but had it for bandwagoning, i.e. the default setup is to front every db server with memcache, this is what sites like facebook do.

Comment: @Discipol that's not a source and from the sounds of it it's not even a typical memcache set-up.